# How to install (and use) Sunrise Commander in Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, sunrise-commander

I'm using Spacemacs and want to try Sunrise Commander (with its ALL plugins!). How to to it with Spacemacs? Is some layer ready for Spacemacs? If not, how to do it w/o layer?

Comment: Please do not post the same question to StackOverflow and to emacs.SE. Pick one or the other. Please delete one of the posts. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

`(sunrise-commander :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "escherdragon/sunrise-commander"))`

to "dotspacemacs-additional-packages" in your .spacemacs or packages.el if you have your own private layer.